# How to call data ref to the user?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I'm having a lot of trouble, How can I render all products that is Referenced to the **user**? What I'm trying to do is, make the user owner of the product, so when I fetch all the table, I will only receive the products created by the user/owner

[image]

This is how I call, and I don't know what function should I use,

```
 router.get('/customerproduct',  async (req,res) =>{
    try {
      const posts = await Product.find()
                    .populate("user_id")
      res.status(200).json(posts)
  
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(404).json({message: error.message})  
    }
})
```

Schema

```
const ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 
    user_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User'},
    title: {type: String},
    description: {type: String},
    categories: {type: Array},
    price: {type: Number},
    productImage: {type: String}
},
{ timestamps: { createdAt: true } }
)

export default mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing things a bit wrong here...

Get the **user_id** from the input HTTP request and then query with find operator.

Example :

input request : **/customerproduct/23ww4f34534534srdfr345** ( querying just a random user id )

API code :

```
 router.get('/customerproduct/:user_id',  async (req,res) =>{
    try {
      const { user_id } = req.params;
      const posts = await Product.find({user_id})
      res.status(200).json(posts)
  
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(404).json({message: error.message})  
    }
})
```

This will find the products having the user_id as : **23ww4f34534534srdfr345**

Hope this helps you, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'm having a trouble because my postman shows 
"63459356209e671c0c160597\n"

I was looking for the next line, and I messed up the URL